# Classes and pointers within classes

Tags: c++, function, class, pointers, header

So a format of the code looks like this:

```
class patient{
public:
    char FirstName[30];
    char LastName[30];
    char SID[20];

};

class Register{
    private:
    int PatientNum;
    patient List[];

    public:
    void OutputList ();

};
```

Then later I've got the function using the Register like so:

```
void Register::OuputList() {...}
```

Now, this is all in a header file. However, when I try to implement the function OutputList() in the main it won't let me. How do I go about this, so in the main the function will compile?

Also, I have another function that was defined outside of the scopes with the patient class such as:

```
patient Add(){...}
```

when using this function in the form of Add(); in main, it works.

=========EDIT==================================================================

I have fixed the problem of compiling and defined a Register pointer object in the main:

```
Register *q;
```

However, my problem now is that the function does not display the data that was taken from the add function. My edited main code for the register::OutputList() is:

```
q -> OutputList();
```

This compiles, however it does not display anything from the add (as it should). I'm thinking its pointing to no assigned memory in the program? Any idea how to fix?

Comment: C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays (like your `Register::List` member). Use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: We actually don't know how he is using the `Register::List` array, maybe he is dynamically allocating memory for it later on (and not changing its size afterwards)? Though in general I would agree that `std::vector<>` is preferable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a Register object before you can call any of its functions. And if you need the pointer then it must be initialized so it points to the object. One way is...

```
Register* q = new Register();
```

Answer (score 0):

> > Now, this is all in a header file. However, when I try to implement the function >>OutputList() in the main it won't let me. How do I go about this, so in the main the function will compile?

I did't get you completely but `Register *q;` is uninitialized in your code;

Comment: Register *q; becomes intitialized in the main. Sorry, bad phrasing on my part